# My socket program doesn't print the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

Just getting started with socket programming, I have created the below code and expecting to print some byte data, but it isn't doing that.

```
import socket

def create_socket():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohl(3))

while True:
    rdata, address = s.recvfrom(65535)
    print(rdata)
```

It just sits and does nothing.

any directions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a server where the requests can be sent by the client to print the data

Below is a sample program where you can send message from client and receive the output that was modified by the server

**SERVER.PY**

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 12048
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
print 'The server is ready to receive'
while 1:
    message,clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
    modifiedMessage = message.upper()
    serverSocket.sendto(modifiedMessage, clientAddress)
```

**CLIENT.PY**

```
from socket import *
serverName = '127.0.0.1'
serverPort = 12048
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
message = raw_input('Input lowercase sentence:')
clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress =clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print modifiedMessage
```

**OUTPUT**

```
SIVABALANs-MBP:Desktop siva$ python client.py 
Input lowercase sentence:siva
SIVA
SIVABALANs-MBP:Desktop siva$
```

EDIT:

Maybe you can try this code

```
import socket
import struct
import binascii

rawSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET,
                          socket.SOCK_RAW,
                          socket.htons(0x0003))

while True:

    packet = rawSocket.recvfrom(2048)
    ethhdr = packet[0][0:14]
    eth = struct.unpack("!6s6s2s", ethhdr)

    arphdr = packet[0][14:42]
    arp = struct.unpack("2s2s1s1s2s6s4s6s4s", arphdr)
    # skip non-ARP packets
    ethtype = eth[2]
    if ethtype != '\x08\x06': continue

    print "---------------- ETHERNET_FRAME ----------------"
    print "Dest MAC:        ", binascii.hexlify(eth[0])
    print "Source MAC:      ", binascii.hexlify(eth[1])
    print "Type:            ", binascii.hexlify(ethtype)
    print "----------------- ARP_HEADER -------------------"
    print "Hardware type:   ", binascii.hexlify(arp[0])
    print "Protocol type:   ", binascii.hexlify(arp[1])
    print "Hardware size:   ", binascii.hexlify(arp[2])
    print "Protocol size:   ", binascii.hexlify(arp[3])
    print "Opcode:          ", binascii.hexlify(arp[4])
    print "Source MAC:      ", binascii.hexlify(arp[5])
    print "Source IP:       ", socket.inet_ntoa(arp[6])
    print "Dest MAC:        ", binascii.hexlify(arp[7])
    print "Dest IP:         ", socket.inet_ntoa(arp[8])
    print "------------------------------------------------\n"
```

I could not test the code in my system as AF_PACKET does not work in mac. Try and let me know if in case it works.

Comment: thank you for the valuable info, but I'm trying to work on the AF_PACKET to capture everything that hits the ethernet layer, not specific to just one port.

Comment: @VigneshSP Can you try the new code and see whether it works ?

Comment: not sure why it is not working, I will try to do some homework on this.